# JAXB unmarshall to multiple pojo's

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I was trying to figure out if it is possible to unmarshall an xml element to multiple pojos. for example:

for xml:

```
<type>
  <id>1</id>
  <cost>12</cost>
  <height>15</height>
  <width>13</width>
  <depth>77</depth>
</type>
```

Item class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlRootElement(name="type")
public class Item {
  private Integer id;
  private Double cost;

  @XmlElement(name="id")
  public Integer getId(){
    return id;
  }

  @XmlElement(name="cost")
  public Double getCost(){
    return cost
  }
}
```

ItemDimensions Class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlRootElement(name="type")
public class ItemDimensions {
  private Integer height;
  private Integer width;
  private Integer depth;

  @XmlElement(name="height")
  public Integer getHeight(){
    return height;
  }

  @XmlElement(name="width")
  public Integer getWidth(){
    return width;
  }

  @XmlElement(name="depth")
  public Integer getDepth(){
    return depth;
  }
}
```

I have tried to accomplish something similar using a number of JAXB mappings generated by Netbeans 6.9 and a number of test classes but have gotten nowhwere. Does anyone know if this is something that can be done without any intermediary objects?

Comment: AFAIK you will have to create the ItemDimensions object yourself. e.g return new ItemDimensions(height, width, depth).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the @XmlPath extension in [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) to accomplish this use case (I'm the MOXy tech lead):

**Root**

JAXB requires a single object to unmarshal, we will introduce a class to fulfill this role.  This class will have fields corresponding to the two Objects you wish to unmarshal annotated with the self XPath:  @XmlPath(".")

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="type")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlPath(".")
    private Item item;

    @XmlPath(".")
    private ItemDimensions itemDimensions;

}
```

**ItemDimensions**

You annotate this class normally.  In your example you annotate the properties, but only provide getters.  This will cause JAXB to think that those are write only mappings.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ItemDimensions {

    private Integer height;
    private Integer width;
    private Integer depth;

}
```

**Item**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    private Integer id;
    private Double cost;

}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Object o = u.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));

        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        m.marshal(o, System.out);
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To use MOXy as your JAXB implementation, you must provide a file named jaxb.properties in with your domain objects with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Comment: +1 I didn't understand the "annotating the getter for write only properties" part , can you elaborate or redirect to link?

Comment: @ekeren - If PROPERTY access is used and no setter is provided then a JAXB implementation won't be able to "set" the value on the object during an unmarshal.  One solution is to provide a setter, the other is to use FIELD access.